# Using a config file in Vue.use

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `index.ts` file I'm configuring my google recaptcha component with the sitekey:

```
Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
    siteKey: 'my_redacted_sitekey'
});
```

this happens before the `new Vue({ ... })` statement.

I don't really want the siteKey hardcoded in the `index.ts` because we would have to redeploy it it would change.

Is there a way to outsource this value to a config file and use it here or is this not possible before the `new Vue({})` statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could place a config file in the `/public` folder and fetch it.  (If you put it in `/src` it will be compiled.)

Simply fetch the config from any module including *main.js* at any time:

```js
axios.get('config.json').then(response => {
  const json = response.data;
  // do something with the config
})
```

<sup>Ex. using axios</sup>

Remember to be mindful of site security as it's in the public folder this way.

There might be a temptation to load the Vue app inside the callback too, but this would cause a blank page until the file is loaded.  It would be better to start the app with a loading message than to delay it with a blank page, for several reasons.